# How to create a feedback survey without using existing templates in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I would like to create survey for feedback about course and teacher. Moodle has 1 tool for collecting feedback from your students : Surveys, but Surveys are a set of predetermined questions already developed by the Moodle developers.

How to create a feedback survey without using existing templates in Moodle?

Answer (score 0):

How about the [feedback module](http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Feedback_module)?

If that doesn't work for you please tell me why, maybe I come up with something else.

Good luck!